# Filter json object in JavaScript with a combination of Union and Intersection

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
const myJSON = {
  "seller1": [
    {
      "product": "headphones",
      "price": 23,
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "product": "earphone",
      "price": 12,
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "product": "iPhone",
      "price": 999,
      "weight": 3
    },
    {
      "product": "ipad",
      "price": 399,
      "weight": 4
    }
  ],
  "seller2": [
    {
      "product": "headphones",
      "price": 25,
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "product": "earphone",
      "price": 10,
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "product": "iPhone",
      "price": 949,
      "weight": 2
    },
    {
      "product": "ipad",
      "price": 449,
      "weight": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to filter myJSON from a multi-select box where, if user selects product: iPhone and product: headphones, I need to display all the products that matches iPhone and headphones. In this case, myJSON will be

```
const myJSON = {
  "seller1": [
    {
      "product": "headphones",
      "price": 23,
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "product": "iPhone",
      "price": 999,
      "weight": 3
    }
  ],
  "seller2": [
    {
      "product": "headphones",
      "price": 25,
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "product": "iPhone",
      "price": 949,
      "weight": 2
    },
  ]
}
```

Now if the user selects different key, price: 449, myJSON should now be empty coz there is not property price: 449 in that anymore. But, if price: 23 then,

```
const myJSON = {
  "seller1": [
    {
      "product": "headphones",
      "price": 23,
      "weight": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

So for example, if user selects 3 items with same key(product), the we should show all the three items that match these 3 items from original json. Now when he selects a different key(price), then we should only filter from the previous result.

Any suggestion on how to implement this is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Lodash provides so many methods to filter collections. Have you looked at its documentation?

Comment: I am just doing a 
const filteredProducts = _.filter(myJSON.seller1, selectedOptions)

but this weird requirement is clouding my mind. Not sure how to do those unions and intersections